# Проблемы с smtplib Python при отправке письма через SSL

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtp, smtplib

Хочу отправить письмо через smtplib, прикрепив к нему файл конфигурации. Для этого написла такой скрипт:

```
import sys
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from config import *

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = 'Screenshort'
msg['From'] = login + "@yandex.ru"

part = MIMEText('Отправляю вам параметры конфигурации')
msg.attach(part)

part = MIMEApplication(open('config.py', 'rb').read())
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename='config.py')
msg.attach(part)

server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(host=host, port=port)
server.ehlo()
server.login(user={login}, password= {passwd})

server.sendmail(msg['From'], 'some@mail.ru', msg.as_string())
```

Но программа выдаёт ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 21, in <module>
    server.login(user={login}, password= {passwd})
  File "smtplib.py", line 723, in login
    (code, resp) = self.auth(
  File "smtplib.py", line 634, in auth
    response = encode_base64(initial_response.encode('ascii'), eol='')
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Как я понял дело в неправильной передачи email-а получателя, но я перепробовал все методы его задать (и как элемент массива ["someemail@...] и как кортеж итп, но ошибка не менялась

Answer (score 1):

Весь код из моего скрипта

```py
import smtplib
import os

from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEBase
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.header import Header

# Данные письма
mail_from = "from@gmail.com"  # отправитель
mail_to = "to@gmail.com"  # получатель
mail_text = "Тестовое письмо!nПослано из python"  # текст письма
mail_subj = "Тестовое письмо"  # заголовок письма
mail_coding = "windows-1251"
attach_file = ""  # ["D:\\test.txt", "D:\\test2.txt"] # прикрепляемый файл

# Параметры SMTP-сервера
smtp_server = "smtp.gmail.com"
smtp_port = 465
smtp_user = "from@gmail.com"  # пользователь smtp
smtp_pwd = "pass"  # пароль smtp

# Формирование сообщения
multi_msg = MIMEMultipart()
multi_msg["From"] = Header(mail_from, mail_coding)
multi_msg["To"] = Header(mail_to, mail_coding)
multi_msg["Subject"] = Header(mail_subj, mail_coding)

msg = MIMEText(mail_text.encode("cp1251"), "plain", mail_coding)
msg.set_charset(mail_coding)
multi_msg.attach(msg)

# Прикрепляем файл
for add_file in attach_file:
    if os.path.exists(add_file) and os.path.isfile(add_file):
        file = open(add_file, "rb")
        attachment = MIMEBase("application", "octet-stream")
        attachment.set_payload(file.read())
        email.encoders.encode_base64(attachment)
        file.close()
        only_name_attach = Header(os.path.basename(add_file), mail_coding)
        attachment.add_header("Content-Disposition",
                              'attachment; filename="%s"' % only_name_attach)
        multi_msg.attach(attachment)
    else:
        if add_file.lstrip() != "":
            print("Файл для атача не найден - " + add_file)

# Отправка
smtp = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, smtp_port)
smtp.ehlo()
smtp.login(smtp_user, smtp_pwd)
smtp.sendmail(mail_from, mail_to, multi_msg.as_string())
smtp.quit()
```

Comment: А что такое Header. Откуда его импортировать?

Comment: from email.header import Header

Comment: Все равно ошибка осталась AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: ```
msg['Subject'] = Header("Subj", "windows-1251")
msg["From"] = Header(login + "@yandex.ru", "windows-1251")
```

Comment: Как я понял ошибка в строке с логином

Comment: То есть дело не в данных о письме все таки

Comment: @BlueScreen дополнил код из моего скрипта для примера. хм... юзер и пароль там вроде просто строка..

Comment: Дело в том что вы используете tls, а я SSL.

Comment: @BlueScreen по сути на логины  пароли и сборку сообщения это не влияет, но изменил так чтобы отсылал сообщения по ssl